# What is と doing there in "…すぎたからと…"

Tags: grammar, particle-と

I came across this example in my N2 book for the the expression 「～ことだ」

> 大きくなりすぎたからとペットを簡単に捨てる人がいる。なんとひどいことだ。

I don't know what's happening there at the "すぎたからと" part. Can someone explain?

Comment: Does it really say 「人い」?   I will let you correct it.

Comment: Oopsy, fixed. Sorry.
But nevermind, it's not the important part, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 大{おお}きくなりすぎたから**と**ペットを簡単{かんたん}に捨{す}てる人がいる。

＝

> 『大きくなりすぎたから。』**と**ペットを簡単に捨てる人がいる。

≒

> 『大きくなりすぎたから。』**と言{い}って/思{おも}って**、ペットを簡単に捨てる人がいる。

The 「と」 is the ***quotative*** 「と」.

> "There are peole who easily abandon their pets saying/thinking that their pets have grown too large."

or

> "There are peole who easily abandon their pets because (they think that) their pets have grown too large."

Comment: Oh oh oh, so that's it huh.
Thank you so much. I was thinking that it's a typo.